# angular and rails form not submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am working a rails app using angular. I have a form inside a main form. the only job that the angular form have is get the text from the input and place in another class. My problem is that the main form is not submitting. I understand i can't nest a form inside a form but that is the only way my angular form works.

```
enter code here

<%= form_for Experience.new, :url => experience_new_path do |f| %>
          <%= f.label :Company, :class => 'control-label' %>
          <%= f.text_field :name,:class => 'form-control' %>
          <br />
          <%= f.label "Job Title", :class => 'control-label' %>
          <%= f.text_field :description,:class => 'form-control' %>
           <br />
          <%= f.label "Location", :class => 'control-label' %>
          <%= f.text_field :description,:class => 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="row" ng-controller="tagForm">
                 <fieldset >
                 <form ng-submit="addEntry()">
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-10 ">
                     <%= f.text_field :description,:placeholder => 'What are your area of     expertise',:'ng-model'=> "newEntry.name", :class => 'form-control border' %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 center form-button" >

                   <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-orange btn-add" >
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-offset-2" id="up" ><br/>
                     <span class="label label-primary" ng-repeat="entry in entries"> {{entry.name}}</span>
                  </div>
                  </form>
                  </fieldset>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-orange btn-lg " value="submit">Add Next      Experience</button>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Rather than using form inside form, you can use button with ng-click handler that would submit data to your backend with angular.

Comment: thank you so much bro. I am still learning